# Future<Widget> can't be assigned to the list type

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, client, future

this is part of my code.
I want to call the search screen class and pass the "client" to it.
so I've called the method read client instead of SearchScreen in the list.
when I've to remove future in the method I've got this error :

```
 The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type
```

and when I've to use future in method, I've got this:

```
error: The element type 'Future<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'. (list_element_type_not_assignable at
```

so how can I call search screen class in the list of the navigation bar?

```
   class MyNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
       Future<void> readClient() async{
      await initHiveForFlutter();
      final HttpLink httpLink = HttpLink("https://test.server.ir/graphql/");
      final AuthLink authLink = AuthLink(
        getToken: () async => 'Bearer <YOUR_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN>',
  );
  final Link link = authLink.concat(httpLink);
  ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient> client = ValueNotifier(
    GraphQLClient(
      link: link,
      cache: GraphQLCache(store:  HiveStore()),
    ),
  );
   runApp(SearchScreen(client: client));
}
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyNavigationBar();
  }
}
```

this part , have a list for call class in navigation bar:

```
class _MyNavigationBar extends State<MyNavigationBar> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> _pages = [
    ExploreScreen(),
    MyNavigationBar().readClient()!,   // this
    LibraryScreen(),
    ProfileScreen(),
  ];

}
```

Comment: Can you include your body widget? And is there any specific reason to run your app on future` runApp(MaterialApp(home: app));`?

Comment: I've edited it. widgets just show the bottom navigation bar.

Comment: Why you are using `runApp` insidewidget  like `runApp(SearchScreen(client: client));`, is there any specific reason?

Comment: just want to call SearchScreen and pass the client in to it

Comment: You can use Navigator instead of  `runApp`.

Comment: would you please write it? I don't understand

Comment: `MyNavigationBar().readClient()!` is  Future, you need to await for fetching. You can use `FutureBuidler` to handle it or `MyNavigationBar().readClient!.then((value) => value);`  but make sure you're assigning data after fetching and to navigate, you need to use `Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SearchScreen(client: client),))`. Without knowing the full widget, it is hard to answer the question.

Comment: https://github.com/siitaw/... here. I've added the repository to see it.

Comment: Folder structure is broken on git, can upload the root project directory. And share git link

Comment: (https://github.com/siitaw/.../blob/main/main.dart)

Answer (score 1):

You're adding several widgets into the `_pages` list (i.e. you've got a `List<Widget>` type), and that's fine, but when you try to add `MyNavigationBar().readClient()!`, well... that's not a `Widget`!

You should add just `MyNavigationBar()` to that list and, eventually, call the `readClient()!` method somewhere else.

Also: why are you using a null-check operator (`!`) on that call? `readClient()` is non-nullable, so that `!` operator is useless at the moment.

Comment: I want to pass the "client" into the search screen. SearchScreen(client : client )

Comment: but I don't know how can I pass the client into the search screen

Comment: You should look up to a state-management solution. If it's your first time hearing this, check out Provider and its stronger brother Riverpod. There are more complex solutions, such as BLoC, but I'd suggest to just stick with Riverpod once you've understood Providers.

Comment: (github.com/siitaw/.../blob/main/main.dart) . would you please see  this

Comment: The link seems to contain some dots in replacement to the actual link, I can't click that?